# How to read arrays from command line and display them using generic method in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm  working on something related to generics in java and I've found this example on the internet [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm). This might be a simple question but I want to find a correct answer from someone who worked with generics. This generic method takes as input argument different types of arrays and displays them. Now I want to do this by reading those arrays from command line. Can you please help me find the correct way to do it? Thanks.

```
public class GenericMethodTest
    {
       // generic method printArray                         
       public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )
       {
          // Display array elements              
             for ( E element : inputArray ){        
                System.out.printf( "%s ", element );
             }
             System.out.println();
        }

        public static void main( String args[] )
        {
            // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
            Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
            Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

            System.out.println( "Array integerArray contains:" );
            printArray( intArray  ); // pass an Integer array

            System.out.println( "\nArray doubleArray contains:" );
            printArray( doubleArray ); // pass a Double array

            System.out.println( "\nArray characterArray contains:" );
            printArray( charArray ); // pass a Character array
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here - is it just "how do I convert the array of Strings from command-line args into an array of .e.g. ints"?

Comment: You want to read the elements of the array through command prompt? And you know how to run the program using command prompt?

Comment: @Doyle ints or double or float or whatever just as you call the method with different arrays i want to input the elements myself and then print them back (I know it's a simple example and stupid ) instead of defining them as `Integer[] bla= {1, 2, 3}`. Then You get a String right? I can make an array of strings and then display them but I would like my method to be called with different arrays not just string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to include the datatype as part of your command line, or else have a routine which detects the type by heuristics. Something like

```
java GenericMethodTest "doubleArray" "1.1 2.2"
```

where you have two args, the type and the array. Then you will need a constructor which converts the second argument from a string to an array, such as

```
public DoubleArray (String sin) {
    String[] ss = sin.split(" ")'
    double dd[] = new Double[ss.length];
    for (String s : ss) {
        dd[i++] = new Double(s);
    }
}
```

I do this sort of thing a lot in scientific programming and I usually end up with special cases for the datatypes. How does the program know what is an integer or a string or a double? You either have to tell it or you have to give it a chance to guess.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I upvoted your answer but it is not really what I was looking for. Maybe my question is a little bit stupid. I actually have a sort method which is generic and I want to sort any type of data I input. As you said the idea is to split the string and construct a Double array. But you don't know what type of data you input. I thought it was something simple enough but I can seem to find the right way to do it. Or maybe I don't have enough experience. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @Michiru - this seems to be the correct answer.  The arguments will *always* be strings; you either have to guess what their type is somehow (which is hard and error-prone), or have the user declare their type (such as the `"doubleArray"` descriptor here).  Then you need to define how to convert from a string to any of these types, and call the correct method.  I don't know what you had in mind, but I can't think of any feasible solution that *wouldn't* involve these two steps.